# Does Spring Supports Interface Injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Does `Spring` supports `Interface Injection completely`?

From “Martin Fowler” Blog it was mentioned that a component that depends on a bean needs to implemented as an `Interface` that injects `Bean`.

When we consider this scenario it will be possible `BeanNameAware`, `XXXAware Interfaces` that injects appropriate bean object.

Is it possible to inject `userdefinedd` Beans using `Interface Injection` other than spring supplied classes.

I am confused with all the above.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct and canonical concept.

You rely on contract (interfaces) and inject them, but container takes care of their implementations:

```
public interface MyService {}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {}

<bean id="myService" class="com.my.proj.MyServiceImpl"/>

public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   private MyService service;

}
```

Don't mix contaier components and its API (`*Aware`) and user-defined application components.